# How to initialize test classes from test suite?

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, junit4

I'm having a test class, which runs test methods based on static data.

```
public SampleTest {
   public static int static_data;

  @test
  public static test() {
    // Test logic using static_data
  }
}
```

this static data i want to pass it from testsuite. 
My test suite looks like this,

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({SampleTest.class, SampleTest.class})
public class SampleTestSuite {

}
```

Before calling SampleTest, each time i want to pass a different sample_data, 
So based on that, different logic can be tested.

I tried with @beforeclass in testSuite, but it's calling only once. 
Is there any annotation, which will be called before calling eatch test class.
So I can pass a different value ?

Comment: try using `@Before`

Comment: Take a look at `Parameterized` tests. See http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

Comment: @before is not getting called in test suite, I think it is useful in test classes only.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349842/junit-4-set-up-things-in-a-test-suite-before-tests-are-run-like-a-tests-befo) approach will do the trick for you.