# Run an initializer in the very beginning of `gradle test` for JUnit 4

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit4

In our project, we have a lot of JUnit 4 tests, and they are executed from Gradle.

Now, we wanted to insert an initializer for the entire "gradle test" execution. The initializer is a class-loading tweak, so it should run just once in the very beginning.

I have looked into some:

- JUnit's `RunListener`

  - `RunListener` does not run on Gradle.
  - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1330
- Similar with `junit-foundation`

  - I was trying this, but it didn't work for unsure reasons yet.

    - It might be because of its complicated classloading structure.
  - Still worth going deeper into it.
- JUnit's `RunWith`

  - We need to specify all the test class names.

    - We already have a lot of test classes.
    - And, when we add a new test class, we have to add the test class there, too. We easily forget.
    - [JUnit 4: Set up things in a test suite before tests are run (like a test's @BeforeClass method, just for a test suite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349842/junit-4-set-up-things-in-a-test-suite-before-tests-are-run-like-a-tests-befo)
  - We wanted all the test classed to be looked up automatically (like normal `gradle test`).

    - [How do I Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4/3257761)
  - `ClasspathSuite` may help to auto-lookup test classes?

    - https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite
  - But, `gradle tests --tests="..."` would not work as intended.
- Static initializer in test classes, to run just once through the entire test run?

  - Need to add so many `static {}` blocks in so many existing tests?
  - Easily to forget, too.

Does anyone have any more ideas to solve this? (If we have a way in JUnit 5, we'll consider that.)

Comment: Does your tweak have to be run from the same JVM process that runs the tests or can it be run in a different JVM process before the tests are run?

Comment: Have to be in the same JVM process.