# How do you find all subclasses of a given class in Java?

Tags: java, class, interface, subclass

How does one go about and try to find all subclasses of a given class (or all implementors of a given interface) in Java?
As of now, I have a method to do this, but I find it quite inefficient (to say the least).
The method is:

1. Get a list of all class names that exist on the class path
2. Load each class and test to see if it is a subclass or implementor of the desired class or interface

In Eclipse, there is a nice feature called the Type Hierarchy that manages to show this quite efficiently.
How does one go about and do it programmatically?

Comment: Although the solution based on the Reflections and Spring look interesting, I needed some simple solution that didn't have dependancies. It seems that my original code (with some tweaks) was the way to go.

Comment: Surely you can use the getSupeClass method recursively?

Comment: I was specifically looking for *all subclasses* of a given class. getSuperClass will not tell you what subclasses a class has, only get the immediate super class for a specific subclass. Also, the method isAssignableFrom on Class is better suited for what you suggest (no need for recursion).

Comment: This question is linked from many other duplicates, but it doesn't contain any useful, plain Java answer. Sigh...

Comment: @EricDuminil See Lyfing answer. Plain Java, constrained search. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is no other way to do it other than what you described. Think about it - how can anyone know what classes extend ClassX without scanning each class on the classpath?

Eclipse can only tell you about the super and subclasses in what seems to be an "efficient" amount of time because it already has all of the type data loaded at the point where you press the "Display in Type Hierarchy" button (since it is constantly compiling your classes, knows about everything on the classpath, etc).

Comment: There is now a simple library called [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) that helps with this and other common reflection tasks.  With this library you can just call `reflections.getSubTypesOf(aClazz))`  [link](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

Comment: @matt b - if it has to scan all the classes, does this means that there is a performance degradation when you have a lot of classes in your project, even though only few of them are sub-classing your class ?

Comment: Exactly. It just touches all classes. You can define your own scanner thou you can speed it up like excluding certain packages you know your class would not be extended or just open the class file and check for finding the class name in the class' constant section avoiding letting the reflection scanner read a lot more information on classes that do not even contain the required reference to your (direct) super class Indirectly you need to scan further. So its the best that there is at the moment.

Comment: The answer by fforw worked for me and should be marked as the correct answer. Clearly this is possible with classpath scanning.

Comment: You're wrong, see the response below about Burningwave library

Comment: They're right, whether or not there is a library to do it.  What do you think the library does / uses?

Answer (score 151):

Scanning for classes is not easy with pure Java.

The spring framework offers a class called [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) that can do what you need. The following example would find all subclasses of MyClass in the package org.example.package

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(MyClass.class));

// scan in org.example.package
Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents("org/example/package");
for (BeanDefinition component : components)
{
    Class cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
    // use class cls found
}
```

This method has the additional benefit of using a bytecode analyzer to find the candidates which means it will *not* load all classes it scans.

Comment: False should be passed in as the parameter when creating ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider to disable the default filters. The default filters will match other types of classes, e.g. anything annotated with @Component. We only want the AssignableTypeFilter to be active here.

Comment: You say it's not easy, but how would we do it if we wanted to do it with pure java?

Answer (score 54):

This is not possible to do using only the built-in Java Reflections API.

A project exists that does the necessary scanning and indexing of your classpath so you can get access this information...

### [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

> **A Java runtime metadata analysis, in the spirit of Scannotations**
>
> Reflections scans your classpath, indexes the metadata, allows you to query it on runtime and may save and collect that information for many modules within your project.
>
> Using Reflections you can query your metadata for:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types annotated with some annotation
> - get all types annotated with some annotation, including annotation parameters matching
> - get all methods annotated with some

(disclaimer: I have not used it, but the project's description seems to be an exact fit for your needs.)

Comment: Interesting. 
The project appears to have some dependancies which their documentation doesn't seem to mention.
Namely (the ones I found so far): javaassist, log4J, XStream

Comment: I included this projekt with maven and it worked fine. Getting subclasses is actually the first source code example and is two lines long :-)

Comment: Is it not possible using only the built-in Java Reflections API or just very inconvenient to do so?

Comment: Please be careful when you are going to use Reflections and then deploy your app WAR to GlassFish! There is a conflict in Guava library and deployment will fail with error **CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408** - please see [GLASSFISH-20579](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20579) for more details. [FastClasspathScanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) is a solution in this case.

Comment: I just try this project and it works. I just use it to enhance the strategy design pattern and get all the strategy concrete class(subclass) I will share the demo latter.

Comment: As stated before, think twice before depending on google reflections. It's not stable because it depends on guava which does not manage versions very well. https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/194

Comment: Is there a good alternative to Reflections? It uses WTFPL and lacks WTFPL headers in the source files, so our project can't use it.

Comment: org.reflections is not maintained very well (no regular releases), lots of open issues and pull requests. Better use ClassGraph or Springs ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider

Answer (score 20):

Try [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph). (Disclaimer, I am the author). ClassGraph supports scanning for subclasses of a given class, either at runtime or at build time, but also much more. ClassGraph can build an abstract representation of the entire class graph (all classes, annotations, methods, method parameters, and fields) in memory, for all classes on the classpath, or for classes in selected packages, and you can query this class graph however you want. ClassGraph supports [more classpath specification mechanisms and classloaders](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/Classpath-Specification-Mechanisms) than any other scanner, and also works seamlessly with the new JPMS module system, so if you base your code on ClassGraph, your code will be maximally portable. [See the API here.](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki/ClassGraph-API)

Answer (score 12):

Don't forget that the generated [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/) for a class will include a list of known subclasses (and for interfaces, known implementing classes).

Comment: this is totally incorrect, super class should not depend on their sub classes,not even in javadoc or comment.

Comment: @hunter I disagree. It is totally correct that the JavaDoc includes a list of _known_ subclasses. Of course, "known" might not include the class you are looking for, but for some use cases it will suffice.

Comment: And you might miss some classes in any case: I can load a new jar into the classpath (during runtime) and every detection that happened before will fail.

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm a few years late to this party, but I came across this question trying to solve the same problem.  You can use Eclipse's internal searching programatically, if you're writing an Eclipse Plugin (and thus take advantage of their caching, etc), to find classes which implement an interface.  Here's my (very rough) first cut:

```
  protected void listImplementingClasses( String iface ) throws CoreException
  {
    final IJavaProject project = <get your project here>;
    try
    {
      final IType ifaceType = project.findType( iface );
      final SearchPattern ifacePattern = SearchPattern.createPattern( ifaceType, IJavaSearchConstants.IMPLEMENTORS );
      final IJavaSearchScope scope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();
      final SearchEngine searchEngine = new SearchEngine();
      final LinkedList<SearchMatch> results = new LinkedList<SearchMatch>();
      searchEngine.search( ifacePattern, 
      new SearchParticipant[]{ SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant() }, scope, new SearchRequestor() {

        @Override
        public void acceptSearchMatch( SearchMatch match ) throws CoreException
        {
          results.add( match );
        }

      }, new IProgressMonitor() {

        @Override
        public void beginTask( String name, int totalWork )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void done()
        {
          System.out.println( results );
        }

        @Override
        public void internalWorked( double work )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCanceled()
        {
          return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setCanceled( boolean value )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void setTaskName( String name )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void subTask( String name )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void worked( int work )
        {
        }

      });

    } catch( JavaModelException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The first problem I see so far is that I'm only catching classes which directly implement the interface, not all their subclasses - but a little recursion never hurt anyone.

Comment: OR, it turns out you don't have to make your own search.  You can just get an ITypeHierarchy directly from your IType by calling .newTypeHierarchy() on it: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg05036.html

Comment: I'm even later ... the OP merely mentioned Eclipse in that Eclipse does what he wants, his "programmatically" statement excludes Eclipse as part of a solution.

Answer (score 9):

I did this several years ago.  The most reliable way to do this (i.e. with official Java APIs and no external dependencies) is to write a custom doclet to produce a list that can be read at runtime.

You can run it from the command line like this:

```
javadoc -d build -doclet com.example.ObjectListDoclet -sourcepath java/src -subpackages com.example
```

or run it from ant like this:

```
<javadoc sourcepath="${src}" packagenames="*" >
  <doclet name="com.example.ObjectListDoclet" path="${build}"/>
</javadoc>
```

Here's the basic code:

```
public final class ObjectListDoclet {
    public static final String TOP_CLASS_NAME =  "com.example.MyClass";        

    /** Doclet entry point. */
    public static boolean start(RootDoc root) throws Exception {
        try {
            ClassDoc topClassDoc = root.classNamed(TOP_CLASS_NAME);
            for (ClassDoc classDoc : root.classes()) {
                if (classDoc.subclassOf(topClassDoc)) {
                    System.out.println(classDoc);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I've removed command line argument parsing and I'm writing to System.out rather than a file.

Comment: While using this programmatically might be tricky, I must say - a *smart* approach!

Answer (score 8):

Keeping in mind the limitations mentioned in the other answers, you can also use [openpojo's `PojoClassFactory`](https://code.google.com/p/openpojo/wiki/Documentation#Reflection_package) ([available on Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Copenpojo)) in the following manner:

```
for(PojoClass pojoClass : PojoClassFactory.enumerateClassesByExtendingType(packageRoot, Superclass.class, null)) {
    System.out.println(pojoClass.getClazz());
}
```

Where `packageRoot` is the root String of the packages you wish to search in (e.g. `"com.mycompany"` or even just `"com"`), and `Superclass` is your supertype (this works on interfaces as well).

Comment: By far the quickest and most elegant solution from the ones suggested.

Comment: Thank you. Very appreciated. A fine solution that is straightforward to use. I used it to get all Serializable classes in my code and fix missing serialVersionUID by generating a test and some code to insert. Very nice to be able to do that! https://gist.github.com/arberg/d867185288b0f36aa908f45d6225c40c

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your particular requirements, in some cases Java's [service loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism might achieve what you're after.

In short, it allows developers to explicitly declare that a class subclasses some other class (or implements some interface) by listing it in a file in the JAR/WAR file's `META-INF/services` directory. It can then be discovered using the [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class which, when given a `Class` object, will generate instances of all the declared subclasses of that class (or, if the `Class` represents an interface, all the classes implementing that interface).

The main advantage of this approach is that there is no need to manually scan the entire classpath for subclasses - all the discovery logic is contained within the `ServiceLoader` class, and it only loads the classes explicitly declared in the `META-INF/services` directory (not every class on the classpath).

There are, however, some disadvantages:

- It won't find **all** subclasses, only those that are explicitly declared. As such, if you need to truly find all subclasses, this approach may be insufficient.
- It requires the developer to explicitly declare the class under the `META-INF/services` directory. This is an additional burden on the developer, and can be error-prone.
- The `ServiceLoader.iterator()` generates subclass instances, not their `Class` objects. This causes two issues:

  - You don't get any say on how the subclasses are constructed - the no-arg constructor is used to create the instances.
  - As such, the subclasses must have a default constructor, or must explicity declare a no-arg constructor.

Apparently Java 9 will be addressing some of these shortcomings (in particular, the ones regarding instantiation of subclasses).

#### An Example

Suppose you're interested in finding classes that implement an interface `com.example.Example`:

```
package com.example;

public interface Example {
    public String getStr();
}
```

The class `com.example.ExampleImpl` implements that interface:

```
package com.example;

public class ExampleImpl implements Example {
    public String getStr() {
        return "ExampleImpl's string.";
    }
}
```

You would declare the class `ExampleImpl` is an implementation of `Example` by creating a file `META-INF/services/com.example.Example` containing the text `com.example.ExampleImpl`.

Then, you could obtain an instance of each implementation of `Example` (including an instance of `ExampleImpl`) as follows:

```
ServiceLoader<Example> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Example.class)
for (Example example : loader) {
    System.out.println(example.getStr());
}

// Prints "ExampleImpl's string.", plus whatever is returned
// by other declared implementations of com.example.Example.
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted as well that this will of course only find all those subclasses that exist on your current classpath.  Presumably this is OK for what you are currently looking at, and chances are you did consider this, but if you have at any point released a non-`final` class into the wild (for varying levels of "wild") then it is entirely feasible that someone else has written their own subclass that you will not know about.

Thus if you happened to be wanting to see all subclasses because you want to make a change and are going to see how it affects subclasses' behaviour - then bear in mind the subclasses that you can't see.  Ideally all of your non-private methods, and the class itself should be well-documented; make changes according to this documentation without changing the semantics of methods/non-private fields and your changes should be backwards-compatible, for any subclass that followed your definition of the superclass at least.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you see a difference between your implementation and Eclipse is because you scan each time, while Eclipse (and other tools) scan only once (during project load most of the times) and create an index. Next time you ask for the data it doesn't scan again, but look at the index.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a reflection lib, which scans your classpath for all subclasses: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

This is how it would be done:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project");
Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use org.reflections library and then, create an object of Reflections class. Using this object, you can get list of all subclasses of given class.
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/Reflections.html

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
    System.out.println(reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add them to a static map inside (this.getClass().getName()) the parent classes constructor (or create a default one) but this will get updated in runtime. If lazy initialization is an option you can try this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I just write a simple demo to use the `org.reflections.Reflections` to get subclasses of abstract class:

https://github.com/xmeng1/ReflectionsDemo

Comment: it would be more productive if you posted a code sample here rather than a link with a lot of classes to dig though.

Comment: Particularly considering the actual code is one or two lines, as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this as a test case, to see if new classes had been added to the code. This is what I did

```
final static File rootFolder = new File(SuperClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
private static ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
listFilesForFolder(rootFolder); 

@Test(timeout = 1000)
public void testNumberOfSubclasses(){
    ArrayList<String> listSubclasses = new ArrayList<>(files);
    listSubclasses.removeIf(s -> !s.contains("Superclass.class"));
    for(String subclass : listSubclasses){
        System.out.println(subclass);
    }
    assertTrue("You did not create a new subclass!", listSubclasses.size() >1);     
}

public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            files.add(fileEntry.getName().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to load all subclassess of given class which are in the same package, you can do so:

```
public static List<Class> loadAllSubClasses(Class pClazz) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = pClazz.getClassLoader();
    assert classLoader != null;
    String packageName = pClazz.getPackage().getName();
    String dirPath = packageName.replace(".", "/");
    Enumeration<URL> srcList = classLoader.getResources(dirPath);

    List<Class> subClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (srcList.hasMoreElements()) {
        File dirFile = new File(srcList.nextElement().getFile());
        File[] files = dirFile.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                String subClassName = packageName + '.' + file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().length() - 6);
                if (! subClassName.equals(pClazz.getName())) {
                    subClassList.add(Class.forName(subClassName));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return subClassList;
}
```

Comment: Just what I wanted - simplified case for limited 'search area'. I wanted to find all subclasses of an abstract base class, all in the same package. This allows 'finding' all the subclasses and managing them (adding/registering them in my case). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

find all classes in classpath

```java
public static List<String> getClasses() {
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        List<String> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (URL url : urlClassLoader.getURLs()) {
            try {
                if (url.toURI().getScheme().equals("file")) {
                    File file = new File(url.toURI());
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        try {
                            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                                for (File listFile : FileUtils.listFiles(file, new String[]{"class"}, true)) {
                                    String classFile = listFile.getAbsolutePath().replace(file.getAbsolutePath(), "").replace(".class", "");
                                    if (classFile.startsWith(File.separator)) {
                                        classFile = classFile.substring(1);
                                    }
                                    classes.add(classFile.replace(File.separator, "."));
                                }
                            } else {
                                JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);
                                if (url.getFile().endsWith(".jar")) {
                                    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
                                    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                                        JarEntry jarEntry = entries.nextElement();
                                        if (jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                                            classes.add(jarEntry.getName().replace(".class", "").replace("/", "."));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return classes;
    }
```

Comment: `(URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();` What if the ClassLoader is not a URLClassLoader?  Believe it or not, not every ClassLoader is.

Comment: @VGR System.getProperty("java.class.path")

Comment: Applications can create ClassLoaders which load classes by means other than the java.class.path property.