# In Java, how to get all possible return types?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, types, return

In Java, a method could be defined as following:

```
Object m(boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        return "123";
    } else {
        return new Integer(123);
    }
}
```

In this case, the return value of m could be either String or Integer in runtime. So is there any way to get all possible run time return types of a method in static time?

Comment: This is known as "bad design".

Comment: some SO comments make my day hahaha

Comment: A method should have Javadoc with a `@return` block tag that describes the return value(s).  If the author didn't document their method, shame (and bad practice) on them.

Answer (score 4):

For this particular method, yes. Just call it with `true` and `false` and check the return value with `getClass()`. For a general case, no.

Generally you wouldn't need to either. Thanks to Java's strong typing and generics, the type of the return value should never be a huge surprise.

Returning multiple different types as shown in your example should be avoided, and in cases where it's useful/necessary (such as factory pattern) it should be irrelevant to the caller.

Comment: Yes, I meant general case. Is there any static analysis tool can do that?

Comment: @jitron Not really. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087401/is-it-possible-to-get-all-the-subclasses-of-a-class

Comment: @jitron What you're looking for is a *very* odd requirement. Does your codebase have a lot of methods with `Object` return type and varying amount of actual types of objects being returned?

Comment: @kayaman Not many Object, but different type could be returned in different branch, for example,  the declared return type could be List, and ArrayList and LinkedList are returned separately in different branch.

Comment: @jitron You're not supposed to care about the actual types. That's what programming to interfaces is all about. Why do you think you need to track the different types? Your example is very poor by the way. A method returning either a `String` or an `Integer` wouldn't pass any code review.

Comment: @Kayaman Because I would like to perform code similarity analysis. If the actual return types of two methods are same, then they are "similar" at some point. And there are some other aspects to define "similar", type is one of them.

Comment: @jitron I think you should concentrate on those other aspects. This seems like a poor choice for measurement of similarity, as well as being unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the implementation of the method, yes. You know all the types it could return because you can read the code and tell for yourself what they are.

But, programmatically? For any method, in general? No, you can't do that, not at run-time. This is why it's **very important** to write good, sensical method signatures with meaningful return-types. Returning `Object` is seldom the best idea. When you say that your method returns `Object`, the contract of that method is that *literally anything* is allowed to come out of it. There's nothing wrong with that, but that's the most specific thing you can say about a method if all you know is its signature.