# How to programmatically find list of classes that have inherited a particular class in Java

Tags: java, reflection, inheritance, superclass

I have a class called MyClass. Is it possible to programmatically find a list of classes that have inherited MyClass? 
I know we can use reflection to discover all the superclasses of a given class, but can we find the subclasses?

Is it even theoretically possible to do so (as I haven't heard of a class being aware of when it is being extended) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at the [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library

---

Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:

- get all subtypes of some type
- get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
- get all resources matching matching a regular expression