# Determining Class Subclasses through Reflection API in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find all subclasses of a given class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java)

I have a super class, `MyClass`, and it is abstract. Anyone can implement it.
At runtime, I need to determine which classes have inherited from this class, using java reflection. How can one do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library.

> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o
>   annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression

Answer (score 3):

A tutorial about that is *[Java Tip 113: Identify subclasses at runtime](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077477/java-tip-113--identify-subclasses-at-runtime.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it (without resorting to external libraries) is to loop through all your classes and check them individually - there's no efficient method built in (nor can there really be, how else would you do it than scanning all the classes since they can be loaded dynamically?)

See Stack Overflow question *[How do you find all subclasses of a given class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java)* for much more detail.