# Automatic factory registration

Tags: java, factory

i'm just learning java, and i meet some problems.
Here we have simple factory pattern:

```
public class SomeFactory {
    ...
     public static void registerProduct(String name, Class<? extends IProduct > f)
}

public SomeProduct implements IProduct {
   static {
       SomeFactory.register("some product", SomeProduct.class);
   }
   ...
}
```

All products should register themselves at factory.

But before using this code, all Products classes should be loaded.
I can put `Class.forName()` somewhere, for example in main function.
But i want to avoid such sort of manual classes loading. I want just add new `IProduct`
implementations, without updating other parts(such as `SomeFactory` or `Main` methods, etc.).
But i wonder, is it possible to automatically load some classes(marked with annotation, for example)?

P.S I want to notice, that no other classes will be added at run-time, all `IProduct` implementations are known before compiling.

**UPD#1**
Thank for your answering!
But is it possible to make auto-generated property-file with `IProduct` instances?
I mean is it possible to make some build-time script(for maven for example) that generates property-file or loader code? Are there such solutions or frameworks?

**UPD#2**
I finished with using [Reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) that provides run-time information, by scanning classpath at startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, but not easily. It would need to scan all the classes in the classpath to see if they have an annotation or implement the `IProduct` interface. See [How do you find all subclasses of a given class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java) for answers to such a problem.

I would do keep it simple and just have a list of classes to load, either in the factory itself, or in an external file (properties file, for example).

Answer (score 3):

1. Have each product register itself, using a static block like this:

   ```
    class MyProduct1{

        static{
            SomeFactory.register(MyProduct1.getClass());
        }
        ..
        ..
    }
   ```
2. An external property file can keep track of all Products.
3. Your main method can parse this list of Products and do a Class.forName("..").

This way you wouldnt need to code any specific product, just the property file keeps changing. Ah! yes adding security registration would also be a plus point.

Note: I'm just proposing an idea, I'vent tried it myself :)

Comment: How is `this.getClass()` going to work in `static { }`?... O_O

Comment: `static { SomeFactory.register(MyProduct1.class) }`