# Java - get extender (child) attribute

Tags: java, oop

Can I get a child attributte in parent class? I see in PHP5 OOP that getting child attribute in parent class is possible, but in Java, I do not know.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example of what you're trying to do? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You need to give a specific example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the subclasses, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java).

Then you can use [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to get the fields and methods of each subclass:

```
for(Class c : subclasses) {
  for(Field f : c.getFields())
    // Do stuff with the fields
  for(Method m : c.getMethods())
    // Do stuff with the methods
}
```

You can look at the [Java API entry on `Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more information.