# how to find sub class list, if we know super class name in java

Tags: java, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find all subclasses of a given class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java)

I am trying to get the sub class name list, if we know super class. I tried through reflection. Seems to be there is no API to get the sub class name list.

```
public abstract class Base{
  /* method implmentation */
}

public class A1 extends Base{
  /* method implmentation */
}
public class A2 extends Base{
  /* method implmentation */
}
```

How to get sub classes names if we know abstract class name "Base"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out this implementation [jprobe](https://code.google.com/p/jprobe/source/browse/trunk/jprobe-1.0/src/org/jprobe/classpath/AbstractClassPath.java)