# How to create instances of all subclasses

Tags: java, reflection, subclass

I have over 250 subclasses that need instances made of them, and I can't sit there and coy and paste `new Class();` 250 times. Is there anyway using Reflection to make an instnace of the classes? No constructor is needed when making the instance.
Thanks.

Comment: We need more info than this. Where should these instances be created for example? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: @Keppil There are no instances, I need to create them. I would need to create them at startup of my program.

Comment: I assume you know names of those classes and have a full list of them and number of instances of each you want create?

Comment: I need this to be dynamic, make a file extend a Superclass and when the program starts, make an instance of the class, no code added.

Comment: If you have a package-qualified class name, you can get an instance using Class.forName(qualifiedName).newInstance(). If you're able to parse/obtain a list of the class names then you're most of the way there. Hard to say without knowing how the instances will be used. Edit: didn't realize they're all subclasses.  Brain's answer looks like it should work.

Comment: There is no way using reflection to get all instances of a class or interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't undesrtand you, but I try to guess (not tested):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class[] classes = new Class[]{Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class};
        for (Class cls : classes) {
            Object myObject = cls.newInstance();
            -------^^^^^^^^-------
        }
    }
}
```

Look at [Creating New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)

EDIT:
May be 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

```
Class.forName("mypackage.MyClassname");
```

Comment: I know that much, but I need to do all that, without having the class name. I need to loop for all of the clases, and check if its superclass is another class (Class.getSuperclass()), and instance it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to [get all the subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/492224/646634). That particular answer seems legitimate, though I haven't tested it myself.

Then iterate through the classes and create the instances using either [`Class.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) (no-args constructors) or [`Class.getConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and [`Constructor.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) when there are parameters for the constructor that you have to pass. The final code will look something like this:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = 
        reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
Set<SomeType> someTypes = new HashSet<SomeType>(subTypes.size());
for (Class<? extends SubType> subType : subTypes) {
    someTypes.add(subType.newInstance());
}
// Do something with someTypes here
```

This will get the subclasses, iterate over them, and create an instance of each one. There are some exceptions here that I'm not doing anything with. You may also have to do some casting (though I don't think you have to).

**Edit:** My answer above will apparently cause some spurious class loading. Create your set of subclasses [like this instead](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/wiki/UseCases#query_the_store_directly,_avoid_definition_of_types_in_class_loa):

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(...); //see in other use cases
Set<String> subTypeFqns = reflections.getStore().getSubTypesOf(SomeClass.class.getName());
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
for (String fqn : subTypeFqns) {
    subTypes.add(Class.forName(fqn));
}
```

Then these lines:

```
for (Class<? extends SubType> subType : subTypes) {
    someTypes.add(subType.newInstance());
}
```

Become this:

```
for (Class<?> subType : subTypes) {
    someTypes.add((SomeType) subType.newInstance());
}
```

Comment: Note that this will get sub-subclasses as well, so you can filter them as you iterate by using `subType.getSuperclass().equals(SomeType.class)`, in case you didn't want them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
Class instantiableClass = Class.forName("package.subpackage.ClassName");
Object instance = instantableClass.newInstance();
```

Only works if your classes have only a default constructor, or public zero args constructor. The code may be looped, generalized or reproduced if you need.

For more general solution [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t137693-find-all-implementing-classes-in-classpath.html) may help you understand why it is not possible. You can do whatever you want with any classes you know, or know their name, or can access their name from any source, or be provided with such minimum information in any way.

But without any knowledge of that classes, it is hardly possible. You would have to seek for all classes in current classpath and then chceck their inheritance tree for compliance with your particular class.

Answer (score 0):

That's a chunk of code to load all the classes of a package, to create new instances for it and to put them in an hashmap (all my classes inherits from Commande):

```
    this.actions = new HashMap<String, Commande>();

    ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL res = classLoader.getResource(COMMAND_DIRECTORY);
    File[] list = new File(res.getFile()).listFiles();
    String className = "";
    for (File f : list) {
        className = f.getName().replaceAll(".class$", "");
        try {
            Class<?> classe = Class.forName("org.commandes." + className);
            if (classe.getSuperclass() == Commande.class) {
                Commande c = (Commande) classe.newInstance();
                this.actions.put(c.getName(), c);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here, COMMAND_DIRECTORY is org/commandes for me.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it's the only way i found to implement the Command design pattern (plugin-like implemented) in a servlet.