# Java - How to import 'Reflections' class?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to use Reflections classes as suggested here
[stackoverflow.com/questions/12538761/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538761/how-to-create-instances-of-all-subclasses)

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = 
        reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
Set<SomeType> someTypes = new HashSet<SomeType>(subTypes.size());
for (Class<? extends SubType> subType : subTypes) {
    someTypes.add(subType.newInstance());
}
```

However, I cant seem to import the necessary package. NetBeans cant find it, and also I tried importing `java.lang.reflections` but it doesn't do it.
I can see `java.lang.Class`, but I don't see `Reflections` class anywhere.

Comment: "I tried importing java.lang.reflections but it doesn't do it." That might just have to do with the fact that there is no such package as `java.lang.reflections`.

Comment: right, it's `java.lang.reflect`. thanks

Comment: Which does not contain the type you're trying to import as the Javadocs clearly show. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-frame.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a library https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections
Add it via Maven, Gradle or manually

Answer (score 4):

[Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) isn't part of Java, it's a 3rd party library. First, you need to add the relevant Jar to your classpath. E.g., if you're using Maven, you could add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you've done that, you need to import the `Reflections` class, as you noted. It is located in the `org.reflections` package:

```
import org.reflections.Reflections
```