# save Java Object to Redis as value

Tags: java, json, object, redis, gson

I want to save a very complex java object to redis as a value. Therefore I have tried to convert this object to Json (gson lib) but it isn't working for my purpose (see other question: [GSON java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class 'xx' declares multiple JSON fields named 'XX' AND StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820389/gson-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-class-xx-declares-multiple-json-field?noredirect=1#comment38532338_24820389)).

I want to **store/serialize** this mentioned complex java object of an application to redis as a value and load back later to the complex java object (consindering the following comment: [Can Jedis get/set an Java POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279117/can-jedis-get-set-an-java-pojo/12355876#12355876)). It is just for evaluation purpose.

How can I accomplish to store this complex object (preferable with json conversion) to redis and back? Every comment would be helpful

---

Update1: The converstion to json and back is working, but with futher process in the application the system is raising a `java.util.LinkedHashMap incompatible with XXX`.

```
  SuperclassExclusionStrategy ex = new SuperclassExclusionStrategy();
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(ex).addSerializationExclusionStrategy(ex).create();

  String json = gson.toJson(daoResult);

  daoResultJson = gson.fromJson(json, JavaObject_DAOListResult.class);
```

There are some objects in the subclasses, which hasn't been converted back in the original state.

---

**Solved**

I have solved my problem in using another lib called [json-io](https://code.google.com/p/json-io/)

Now I can work perfectly fine with with my object. In Gson there were a lot of null properties whis were missing in the json string. With json-io the null properties were converted as well. Here is the solution:

```
 // convert daoResult to JSON
 jsonIO = JsonWriter.objectToJson(daoResult);
 // convert stored JSON to daoResult
 daoResultJson =  (DAOListResult) JsonReader.jsonToJava(jsonIO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix your other issue in converting your object to JSON, which is separate from this question, I guess, you can just set your JSON string to a Redis key, and then get it back later:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET blah '{"some": "x", "some_other": "y"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET blah
"{\"some\": \"x\", \"some_other\": \"y\"}"
```

You'll need to build a serializer/deserializer between your Java object and JSON, but this is all you need to do with Redis. You could alternatively use a Redis Hash with `HSET` and `HGET` to accomplish the same, but you don't provide enough information in your question for me to be able to recommend which is better for your situation.

Comment: I was able to convert the complex java object to json and the otherway around but the further processing of the complex object has raised a error `java.util.LinkedHashMap incompatible with XXX`

Comment: The current problem is to convert the Json String back to the original object, with the giving error `java.util.LinkedHashMap incompatible with XXX`