# Getting output in JSON format in UIMA

Tags: java, json, uima, ctakes

I'm using [Apache cTAKES](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizhsCP8srQAhVKNI8KHde2A4UQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fctakes.apache.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHT5KCcHT3TP2stojzMAquLsf3SDw&sig2=47NxRugREbDS3jP-o-Q-CQ) where the output is required in JSON. I'm trying google's [gson](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjp7ejh88rQAhWBPY8KHcO5CoEQFgg8MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.github.io%2Fgson%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgson%2FGson.html&usg=AFQjCNGjvEPjxXSPfigx5L9pfVUJPhAV6w&sig2=_68wPhbazRWB6E52jijf2w) here,

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException, UIMAException, SAXException {
    final String note = "Serum Cholesterol 154 150 250 mgs/dl\n-\nSerum Triglycerides 67 90 200 mgs /dl\n-\nSerum HDL: Cholesterol 38 35 55 mgs /dl\n-\nSerum LDL: Cholesterol 49 85 150 mgs/d1\n-\nSerum VLDL: Cholesterol 13 10 40 mgs/dl\n-\nTotal Cholesterol / HDL Ratio: 3.90\";
    final JCas jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
    jcas.setDocumentText(note);

    final AnalysisEngineDescription aed = getFastPipeline(); 
    SimplePipeline.runPipeline(jcas, aed);

    Collection<TOP> codes = JCasUtil.selectAll(jcas);
    List<TOP> list = new ArrayList<>(codes)

    TOP [] res = list.toArray(new TOP[list.size()]);
//   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
    String json = new Gson().toJson(res);
    System.out.println(json);

}
```

This returns with the following errors,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.apache.uima.jcas.tcas.DocumentAnnotation_Type declares multiple JSON fields named fsGenerator
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:93)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:565)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:520)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:500)
at org.apache.ctakes.clinicalpipeline.ExtractNEs.main(ExtractNEs.java:146)
```

Any guidance would be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: What is `TOP` ? With the given exception message, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476513/class-a-declares-multiple-json-fields

Comment: TOP is org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.TOP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I found for this is to use [JsonCasSerializer](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.7.0/apidocs/org/apache/uima/json/JsonCasSerializer.html), which has a method 
`static void    jsonSerialize(CAS aCAS, Object output)`
,where one parameter is CAS document and other is a writer.

My updated code is,

```
public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException, UIMAException, SAXException {
     final String note = "Serum Cholesterol 154 150 250 mgs/dl\n-\nSerum Triglycerides 67 90 200 mgs /dl\n-\nSerum HDL: Cholesterol 38 35 55 mgs /dl\n-\nSerum LDL: Cholesterol 49 85 150 mgs/d1\n-\nSerum VLDL: Cholesterol 13 10 40 mgs/dl\n-\nTotal Cholesterol / HDL Ratio: 3.90\";
     final JCas jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();
     jcas.setDocumentText(note);

     final AnalysisEngineDescription aed = getFastPipeline(); 
     SimplePipeline.runPipeline(jcas, aed);
     CAS cas = jcas.getCas();
     JsonCasSerializer jcs = new JsonCasSerializer();
     jcs.setPrettyPrint(true); // do some configuration
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     jcs.serialize(cas, sw); // serialize into sw

     System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

This gave me an output of the document in JSON.

A clear usage is given [here](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.7.0/references.html#ugr.ref.json.usage).

Comment: I tried following the above code, but am getting the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`.

This may be native to CTakes 4.0.0 - do you know which version this was run with?

Comment: The version being used is **3.2.3**, as for the error you are getting, you need to be more specific, and as to what I remember, similar error i got was to access lvg.properties within a jar, try referring this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CTAKES-385