# Getting a enum constant declared in imported class, via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Having something like:

```
import com.example.test.classA;
import com.example.test.classB;
import com.example.test.classC;

public class MyClass {
    ...
    Flavors p = Flavors.VANILLA;
    ...
    String flavorChoice = "Flavors.CHOCOLATE";
    ...
}
```

where `Flavors` is an `enum` declared in one of the imported classes:

```
public enum Flavors { CHOCOLATE, VANILLA, LEMON };
```

How can I get a value, using reflection, from the string `flavorChoice`?
Do not assume I know in which imported class `Flavors` is declared.
Do not even assume that `Flavors` is accessible from within `MyClass`.

**CLARIFICATIONS**
The string `flavorChoices` should produce an `Object`, the object may be, in the example above it is, of type `Flavors`. But it also may refer to other constants in other enums:

```
String flavorChoice = "ExtraFlavors.MENTA";
String flavorChoice = "ExoticFlavors.CHALK";
String flavorChoice = "AnyEmun.ANYCONSTANT";
```

I don't know what the string contents are until runtime. I want to be able to:

1. Check the referred enum indeeed exists and is accessible from MyClass
2. Get the referred enum constant and put it in an `Object`

Comment: If you don't know which particular `Flavors` class to refer to, then how could this ever work?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492184/732016), with some adaptations, could be of use?

Comment: Realistically, though, why wouldn't you know where the class `Flavors` is declared? Even if you get it with reflection, you'd only be able to store it as an `Object` (or an `Enum<?>`) if you haven't imported it...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's why I put the line `Flavors p = Flavors.VANILLA` in the example, to show that without reflection I can use `Flavors` without knowing exactly where it is declared. For the sake of simplicity, if it helps you to formulate an answer, assume there is only one `Flavors` declared in the system.

Comment: @WChargin Ralistically, I know where `Flavors` is declared. What I don't know beforehand is the string `flavorChoice`, which can refer to any `enum` that is visible in that scope. It Even can refer to some `enum` that is not accessible there, in which case I want to call a `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

If string is re-defined as following:

`String flavorChoice = "CHOCOLATE";`

you even do not need reflection. Just use `Flavors.valueOf(flavorChoice)`.

In your case you can say:

```
String choice = "Flavors.CHOCOLATE";
String[] fragments = choice.split("\\."); 
Enum.valueOf(Class.forName(fragments[0]), fragments[1]);
```

`Class.forName(fragments[0])` will return you your `enum`'s class, `Enum.valueOf()` returns the element of the `enum`.

EDIT:
If in real-world case your classes belong to package you should improve the parsing by replacing `split()` to something else.

Comment: As long as I need to provide the class for `Class.forName()` this does not help me. I need a way to check if `Flavors` is a known class in the scope (note that *"known class in the scope"* is much broader than checking for the current object subclasses, it may be a class is know because of `import` or because some parent class up in the hierarchy declared it)

Comment: @ilomambo: AFAIK, there is no information about lexical scope available to the reflection mechanism.  So it may be that what you're asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `Flavors` class, as suggested by the example, the `valueOf` method may be useful:

> Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified name. The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace characters are not permitted.)

Thus:

```
Flavor f = Flavors.valueOf("VANILLA");
```

If your question is how to extract `VANILLA` from `Flavors.VANILLA`, you could try:

```
Flavor f = Flavors.valueOf("Flavors.VANILLA".replaceAll("^.*\\.", ""));
```

where `*` is a greedy quantifier.

The advantage of using regex over `split("\\.")[1]` is that if the parameter came in with a greater qualification, like `classA.Flavors.VANILLA` or `com.example.test.classA.Flavors.VANILLA`, the regex would still work. Alternatively, you could use:

```
String[] parts = "Flavors.VANILLA".split("\\.");
String flavorPart = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: better regex - it will work with `SomeClass.Flavors.VANILLA` too.

Comment: You should use it in your split too then

Comment: @assylias I added the `split` part to show that you can do it with even the simplest regex because some people don't like using complicated regex. If this were the case I actually think it would be better to do `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(".").split(identifierString)` but maybe that's just me...

Comment: @WChargin Addition to my reply comment to you in the original question. If I could use `Flavors` that would be fine, but note that I wrote *"Do not even assume that Flavors is accessible from within MyClass"*. Maybe the question is oversimplified, I will add some clarifications there.

Comment: If you can do `Flavors p = Flavors.VANILLA` then you can call `Flavors.valueOf` ; am I missing something?