# What is the best way to call methods from all the subclasses of an abstract class?

Tags: java, foreach, abstract-class

I want to make API calls to a bunch of different API services. I have an abstract class called `ApiService` that contains common methods for each subclass. Every new API will have to inherit and implement these methods.

My question is: how can I go through all the subclasses of `ApiService` and call their methods?

Right now, I have a static array of all the services instantiated already (which means that new services must be manually added to the array) that looks something like this:

```
ApiService[] services = {new SubService1(), new SubService2(), ...};
```

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

Comment: I think this link will be useful. Check it please. 

[Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You want to call a method on each instances of subclasses of an abstract class. There is no automatic way to find all the instances of a class anyway, so you need to manage the list of all instances yourself.

You have to do one of the following:

- manage the list manually, that is add instances to the list when you create them
- make that more automated, by adding the instance to a static list in the constructor of your base class `ApiService`. But it makes the base class aware of the list of its instances, and it seems to me a bit of a code smell.

There is another alternative, when you know the number of instances in your application in advance: use an Enum instead of an abstract class. Each Enum value is an instance of the class, and it can implement interfaces and methods, and each instance can override a method differently.