# Java - How to find all direct subclasses of a class with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, subclass

I need to make a list of all the direct subclasses of a specific class using reflection, is there any way to do it?

Comment: AFAIK, There is no method to do that.

Comment: what do you mean by **possible**?

Comment: I mean all the classes that directly extend a specific class

Comment: I need only the direct ones Richard and maybe there is a way to do that :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java

Comment: Use the search, Luke! Or, you know, look at that list of things that popped up when you typed the title of your question ...

Comment: There is no way of doing this within the Java API, but there are reflection libraries that can do this for you. [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) comes to mind.

Comment: the problem is that I don't need all the subclasses but just the direct ones. Some people say in that topic that it's not possible and some other give not efficient or hard methods. Since I'm just looking for the direct ones I'd like to know if there is an easy way to do that (I don't like to scan paths for example)

Comment: @DomenicoToscani well, finding the direct subclasses is not easier than all subclasses. A super class doesn't store any information about its subclasses, so the only way to find them is by inspecting all classes on the class path (whether you like that or not ;-) )