# Is it possible to get the classtype of a class which is located in a different library?

Tags: java, reflection

i have a JAVA library, which adds a lot of functionality to a class. The lib is packed within a .jar file and the functionality is implemented (generics) in Class A (Package a.jar)

Application BApplication includes package a.jar and contains a class B which derives from A:

```
LIB A: 
class A { 
    public instanciate(String json){ ... } 
    private addToList(){ ....}
    public XY()...
}
```

now in the deriving library:

```
LIB B uses A:
class B extends A {..}

SomeClass{
    new B.XY();
}
```

Now i have to know the Class B within the library a.jar. (during runtime)

I can imagine, that the library (or class) must notice when another library (or class) uses it (at least during runtime)..

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what you are asking.  Can you provide more detail?  Specifically, can you explain what you need to do and why.

Comment: Why should "A" know anything about "B"? At the time A is implemented you might not even have a thought on B.

Comment: @GyroGearless: the a.jar creates instances out of json. Therefore it is important to know about the classes. Until now the class B must be registered in the framework but this is not a good solution in my eyes. Why should A not know about B when it is extending A? I think that A is informed as parent, when the child B is "born" :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any easy way to do this.
You would have to loop through the loaded classes and check each one.
Check [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip113.html?page=2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java).

Comment: Sounds quite OK but still as a temporary solution. I think this is to slow. Does the RuntimeEnvironment have any hooks to listen for "deriving" or at least on "instanciating"?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I am following your question with enthusiasm to see if someone posts a better solution :)