# find subclasses of a given class in jdk lib

Tags: java, subclass

I did search the solution for finding all subclasses for a given class and I saw  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java/28020386#28020386)

As far as I know, there are some tools to do that such as Reflections, using  `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` in Spring framework, or extcos.
But after trying them all, seems none of them works for a given class in jdk (List, Map, Number, ...).
I looked into their source code, see how they work, I think the reason is because they need to get the package in which we look for the subclasses as resource, and the function `classloader.getResource(String name)`, always returns null for a package name in jdk.
So, why `classloader.getResource(String name)` returns null for a package name in jdk? and does anyone know a solution to get subclasses that works for jdk as well?

Comment: Can you add an example what resource was not found? If you run `System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("java/lang/String.class"));` you will get an url.

Comment: This is what I tried : ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("java/util"); It returns value if I get resource for a path of another package not in jdk

Comment: As the post said,you have to scan all the classes in the jdk to get all the subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not try one of the solutions from your link?

Find below a simple example using `https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections.git`.

After having a look in the `test` classes this example was straight forward.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setUrls(Arrays.asList(ClasspathHelper.forClass(List.class))));

Set<Class<? extends List>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(List.class);
for (Class c : subTypes) {
    System.out.println("subType: " + c.getCanonicalName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. I did try the Reflections, but not using the configuration, and only focus on extcos for better performance :)