# How to get all subclass from base class in JAVA

Tags: java, class, reflection, subclass

I have a base class such as :

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

}
```

and I also have sub classes :

```
public class SubClassA extends BaseClass{}
public class SubClassB extends BaseClass{}
public class SubClassC extends BaseClass{}
```

I want to get all sub classes by Base class like below:

```
List<Class> getSubClassesByBaseClass(BaseClass.class);
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: The tool you intend to use: https://code.google.com/archive/p/reflections/

Comment: Can you check this plz? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java