# TestSuite Setup in jUnit 4

Tags: java, junit, installation, test-suite

I've managed to find out how to make a TestSuite in jUnit 4, but I really miss the v3 possibility of wrapping a suite in a TestSetup.

Any ideas as to how to get some @BeforeClass/@AfterClass setup executed for a suite of test cases in jUnit 4?

I.e.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class})
public class MyTestSuite {
    @BeforeClass public static void setUpClass() {
        // Common initialization done once for Test1 + Test2
    }
    @AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() {
        // Common cleanup for all tests
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code fragment doesn't work. `@BeforeClass` only works on a per-test-class basis.

Comment: According to this answer it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82949/before-and-after-suite-execution-hook-in-junit-4-x#177069

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is what I have and it runs just fine.

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestSuite1.class, TestSuite2.class })
public class CompleteTestSuite {

    @BeforeClass 
    public static void setUpClass() {      
        System.out.println("Master setup");

    }

    @AfterClass public static void tearDownClass() { 
        System.out.println("Master tearDown");
    }

}
```

Here is my test suite 1 (do the same for test suite 2).

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(value = Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses(value = { TestCase1.class })
public class TestSuite1 {}
```

And here is my test class. Create both testcase1 and testcase2.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCase1 {

    @BeforeClass 
    public static void setUpClass() {      
        System.out.println("TestCase1 setup");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertEquals(2 , 2);
    }
}
```

you should have 5 classes 
completesuite
suite1
suite2
test1
test2

and make sure you have Junit in your build path. This should run!

Here is the output

```
Master setup
TestCase1 setup
Master tearDown
```

Comment: What! It actually works! Geez, I wonder how come I couldn't get it to work yesterday (probably just a blunder on my part then).

Comment: Awesome solution! Even in my scenario where a custom test scanner creates the list of tests.