# Single server instance should run all the integration test in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

I am writing a set of integration tests and each test class start the server and stop the server, which takes long time. Is it possible to create a test suite, where a single instance of server can be used for a set of test classes?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Assuming you are using JUnit, then the start and stop server actions can take place in the setup and teardown methods. All tests in the same class can then use the server instance.

Comment: You don't need setup or tear down, as Spring will do it for you. Question was about creating a set of classes under a single suite.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580670/testsuite-setup-in-junit-4

Comment: That a nice option, but it needs a different runner, and so we won't able to use spring runner. But its a good option if we want to run the test server manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a Java EE application is designed to run in a Tomcat container, should all integration tests run in a similar container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657249/if-a-java-ee-application-is-designed-to-run-in-a-tomcat-container-should-all-in)