# send parameters from test suite to test case in junit 4

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-suite

I've got four junit cases and I need to pass them a parameter, that is the same for all of them, but this parameter is created in a dynamic way in the test suite. How can I pass a parameter from the test suite to all the tests in the test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its just a string parameter, you can set the System Property and access it in test cases.

If you want to programmatically do it, you can do it at one place `System.setProperty("x","123");` otherwise you can always pass System properties from command line as `-Dx=123`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but can you explain that, i mean if i have this class                                      @RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestAddTag.class })
public class AllTests {

}                                                                    How pass to the test TestAddTag a string parameter?

Comment: Can you try this in the static initializer? `@RunWith(Suite.class) @SuiteClasses({ TestAddTag.class }) public class AllTests { static {System.setProperty("x","123");} } ` can then do `System.getProperty("x")` in your test case.

Comment: the static block didn't take effect, so I went with: http://www.coderanch.com/t/534637/Testing/JUnit-pass-parameters-Test-classes

Comment: @pulkitsinghal did you get that to work with junit 4 tests cases?

Comment: this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/177069/51292) worked for me, but required a suite class for each option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use system property, try to use a static class, store a class with all info that you want in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try parameterized tests. It is a built-in JUnit feature designed to pass parameters to all tests inside a test case. See below link for examples:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests