# Handle post login pages with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am having more 25 test scripts which cover the post login page element.now, while running as suite,each time a browser is opened and login credentials were entered and post login elements were checked.which consumes more time. Is there a solution to share the login page with credentials across the test execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think time is not consumed on type user/password, because it is just a moment. A time is spent on browser open/close each test.

If you want to save time, login once before whole test suite and then start each test with 'home' page. Details how to keep your `driver` opened you may found here: [Use same web driver throughout selenium suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990683/use-same-web-driver-throughout-selenium-suite)