# Benchmark JUnit AllTests

Tags: java, junit

Is there a way to place simple start/stop timing in a JUnit test suite?

When I create a test suite class, it looks like this and I can run it. But how could I put a simple long start time variable in here to show how long all the tests took to run?

```
public class AllTests {

    public static Test suite() throws Exception {
        TestSuite theTestSuite = new TestSuite();
        theTestSuite.addTest(com.company.AllBlahTests.suite());
        theTestSuite.addTest(com.company.AllOtherTests.suite());
        return theTestSuite;
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you running the tests?  These results are usually reported automatically by the framework running the tests.

Comment: Yeah they are - I can get these from the run but I was just wondering how to get them programmatically.  I use IntelliJ and just right-click and run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer to a previous question. [Before and After Suite execution hook in jUnit 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82949/before-and-after-suite-execution-hook-in-junit-4-x#177069)

If you implement that solution, you may be able to place your timing code in the setup and teardown methods of the suite class.