# How to Increase the Performance of Unit Tests that Need to Load Very Large File

Tags: java, performance, unit-testing, junit

I have a Java NLP project that I am working on which uses [Stanford's CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) package. I have several unit tests for the project and I like to run them frequently in order to see how minor tweaks impact the system's output. Unfortunately, the CoreNLP package needs to load [a model of the English language](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download) in order to perform its classification and tagging, and this file is so large that it takes several seconds to load into memory. This may not seem like much wait time but it seems a shame that the unit tests themselves take milliseconds to run and each time I start a new test run I have to wait for the model file to load.

Is there any way to have the model file loaded once and subsequent unit test runs are run against that model which is already in-memory? Perhaps something like a test "server" that stores the model and can be called from the unit tests? I have never dealt with something like this before so I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Load the model once in a static method [before your suite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82949/before-and-after-suite-execution-hook-in-junit-4-x).

Comment: I do load the model once in a static method. Sorry if I wasn't clear: I want to load the model once per computer boot-up. Essentially, only the first suite run will be slow, all other suite runs should be fast. Does that make sense? I'm not sure how best to phrase it.

Comment: To reuse the data between runs, you need to load it into a form which can be used in shared memory. e.g. a memory mapped file.  Not sure it is worth it.  If it adds a few second to your entire run of unit tests it is probably not work changing.

Comment: First thing to do would be to check the basics: what is the code used to load the file? Do you have an SSD?

Comment: I've actually hacked together a working solution using Java RMI. The server loads the file in and just sits there waiting for invocations from the unit tests. Not sure if this is ideal though.

Comment: JB Nizet: The code used to load the file is in the Stanford CoreNLP package so I can't really change that. I am using an SSD to load the file.

Comment: How is the file loaded? Using a `InputStream` or `Reader`? How big it is?

Answer (score 1):

In unit-testing, the typical solution for such a scenario is to isolate your code from the 'disturbing' libraries (that is, eliminate the dependency) or use doubles (like stubs or mocks).  Unit-testing against actual data bases is considered a 'test smell'.

Comment: I think it's not so much a smell as it is something that by definition turns the tests into integration tests, not unit tests. it's not "bad", it's just another thing. shouldn't mix them up though

Comment: Completely agree. Unit test is not the correct term here, it really is an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you are on a modern operating system such as Linux, subsequent reads of the same file within a short amount of time will be cached by the [buffer cache](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html) - unless the file is very large or you are short on free memory. This is not just theoretical - you can easily run a JUnit test with some profiling that shows that loading a file multiple times will result in near `memcpy` speeds for all but the first load, as long as the file approximately fits in free RAM.

That is, the file will generally load at 5 GB/s or faster on modern desktop or server hardware as long as it is in the cache. If the file is too big to keep in the cache - then a lot of the other solutions are already excluded: since the alternatives such as a daemon keeping the file in shared memory would require the same amount of RAM anyway.

That's all talking about the raw cost of reading the file (e.g., using Java's InputStream or other classes which read the raw file). It's entirely likely that the true cost of "loading" the file is in the application specific parsing you need to do to bring the file into the expected in-memory format. In that case, you could certainly consider some kind of long-lived cache process that keeps a file in memory across Java invocations. You could use something off the shelf like redis or memcached, but you'd have to make sure that your deserialization scheme was then at much faster than your parsing scheme.

Ultimately you need to profile the library's load of the problematic file. Is it IO limited (i.e., most time spent blocking in IO functions), or is it CPU limited (e.g., most time spend processing in parsing or other functions)? Only then can you determine at what level you need to cache at to be useful.