# Junit suites @Before/@AfterClass

Tags: java, junit, test-suite

We've encountered a problem which we have few test classes, each one of them has it's own `@BeforeClass` logic. 
We want that in case we run tests from suite, Test's `@AfterClass` won't be executed as it will cause a conflict with the suite `@AfterClass`.

(In our case, we are running a docker container in `@BeforeClass` and kill it in `@AfterClass` of each test class. 
But once we run tests through suite, we want this opearation will be executed only once in suite before and after class).

We know that we can a set a system property in suite `@BeforeClass` (and to check it in before class of test classes) but we wonder if there is some built in solution for our problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For such integration test, i would rather choose a JUnit Rule instead of Before(Class) Annotions to init environments such as docker. This might help you [integration-tests-with-a-docker-junit-rule](https://geowarin.github.io/integration-tests-with-a-docker-junit-rule/)

Comment: Have a look at using a custom RunListener: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757266/2210137